# plotting many graph with matplolib (bargraph)

Tags: matplotlib

I have , dictionary

```
st={'Google Phone': [318, 379, 463, 580, 479, 391, 411, 359, 341, 597, 493, 714],
 'iPhone': [381, 439, 537, 691, 640, 533, 501, 439, 396, 715, 664, 906],
 'Vareebadd Phone': [125, 129,174,220,185,155,146,141,126,203,177,284]}
```

where all values in list are in following order:

```
Vareebadd Phone<Google phone<iphone
```

like---->381>318>125         ||      439>379>129 for all values with same index
i got :

[image]

now if I put some change in

```
st={'Google Phone': [318, 379, 463, 580, 479, 391, 411, 359, 341, 597, 493, 714],
 'iPhone': [381, 439, 537, 691, 640, 533, 501, 439, 396, 715, 664, 906],
 'Vareebadd Phone': [125, 129,174,220,185,155,146,141,126,203,177,910]}
```

i got this:

[image]

my code is:

```
monthsname=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','July','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']

plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))    
plt.xticks(xpos,monthsname)
plt.bar(monthsname,st['iPhone'],w,label='iPhone')
plt.bar(monthsname,st['Google Phone'],w,label='Google Phone')
plt.bar(monthsname,st['Vareebadd Phone'],w,label='Vareebadd Phone')

# plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to other packages, consider `Pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(st,index=monthsname ).plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

Or for the second data frame:

[image]

Is it what you are looking for?